User E-commerce account activation. PHP, jQuery
I created a login page and I have successfully login into the home page. my problem is that the id of the user is not sent to the home when i login. I intend to use the id to display the cart icon when the user is in the home page.
this code below shows post request sent to the API and logins the user into the home page.
 $.post('/controller/user.php', { request: "login", password, username }, function (response) {
    // covert json string resp to js obj
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    if (response.status == "success") {
        customAlert("Account login successfully", "success", 3000);
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.location = "/";
        }, 1500);
    } else {
        customAlert(response.message, "error", 3000);
    }
}).fail(function () {
    return customAlert("could not send request, kindly check your internet connection", "error", 3000);
})

with this code the user can login from the register page but my is that at the Home page the userName and id isnt sent to validate it
here is the icon i want to be active if the user is on the account.
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{ echo'<a href="#" class="single-icon"><i class="ti-bag"></i> <span class="total-count">2</span></a>';}else{
    echo'';
}
?>


Is the PHP code in your question part of /controller/user.php or part of /?

I will edit my post. I am learning actually. I create a login page and I have successfully login into the Home page, my problem is that the Id of the user is not sent to the home when i login. I intend to use the id to display the cart Icon when the user is in the home page.

If you want $_POST['id'] to contain a value, you have be posting to the PHP script in your question and the payload should contain the id. Nothing in your question indicates that you're doing this. See: $_POST. You are using JQuery to post to /controller/user.php, but there's no id in the data (= payload) you send.

Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem? How is it related to phpMyAdmin?

I think you need to use the server to remember that the user has logged in. This is usually done with PHP sessions. Here's a tutorial on PHP sessions.

Try to think about the security of your E-commerce site. Which data is safe to show publicly? What can you do to sanitize data that is coming in from the outside world? It's best to learn how to secure your websites from the start, because fixing it afterwards is a nightmare. Here's a nice starter blog.
